# How to get a resource value in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The `resValue` method (or whatever it's called) allows you to *set* a resource value in `buildTypes` or `productFlavors`.  **Is there a corresponding way to *get* a resource value that was set by `resValue`?**

It appears that `productFlavors` is evaluated before `buildTypes`, so a `resValue` set in `buildTypes` takes precedence.  I want to append "Debug" to the app name in debug builds, but I need to get the value that was set in the product flavor in order to append to it.

**Edit:** I tried Marcin Koziński's suggestion to use a variable, but *all* product flavors are evaluated before *any* build type.  Therefore, this does not work:

```
android {
    String appName = ""

    productFlavors {
        Foo {
            appName = "Foo"
        }

        Bar {
            appName = "Bar"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", appName 
        }

        debug {
            resValue "string", "app_name", appName + " Debug"
        }
    }
}
```

In `buildTypes`, `appName` always has the value from the *last* product flavor.  So in this example, all builds receive the name `"Bar"` or `"Bar Debug"`.

Basically, I need a `resValueSuffix` analogous to `applicationIdSuffix`.  Apparently no such animal exists.  Does the `com.android.application` plugin expose anything that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275461/how-to-replace-strings-resources-with-android-gradle

Comment: @TimCastelijns That Q&A is about resources from `strings.xml`.  My resource is created with `resValue`.

Comment: Is  `app_name` used in your app anywhere besides the manifest?

Comment: There is a way you can do it with manifest placeholders, see my answer below.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are only trying to set the App Label (or other manifest values) you can solve this with [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables).

```
android {

    productFlavors {
        Foo {
             applicationId "com.myexample.foo"
             manifestPlaceholders.appName = "Foo"
        }

        Bar {
             applicationId "com.myexample.bar"
             manifestPlaceholders.appName = "Bar"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders.appNameSuffix =""
        }

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders.appNameSuffix =".Debug"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Android Manifest you simply use both placeholders for your app name (or other values)

```
 <application
        android:label="${appName}${appNameSuffix}"
        ...
 </application>
```

This allow you to install all 4 variants side by side on a single device as well as give them different names in the app drawer / launcher.

**EDIT** 11/22/2019

Updated how placeholders values are set based on feedback from @javaxian

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.

Comment: I would still be curious how the OPs question can be answered in regards to getting resource value in gradle...

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, if it is I have never been able to figure it out.

Comment: maybe this link can help you for reading from resource file using gradle: http://veltema.jp/2014/08/27/generating-strings.xml-from-JSON-at-Build-in-Android-Studio/

Comment: I ran into some dire conflicts when using this otherwise great method due to the fact that one of my libs, namely Localytics, also used manifestPlaceholders. All I needed to change is set only the placeholder I wanted, i.e. `manifestPlaceholders.appNameSuffix = ".Debug"` rather than `manifestPlaceholders = [ appNameSuffix:".Debug"]`.

Answer (score 8):

You can check the build variants like this

Define values in gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        buildConfigField "String", "Your_string_key", '"yourkeyvalue"'
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_URL", '"some text"'
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG", 'true'
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "Your_string_key", '"release text"'
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_URL", '"release text"'
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG", 'false'

    }
}
```

And to access those values using build variants:

```
 if(!BuildConfig.LOG)
      // do something with the boolean value
```

Or

```
view.setText(BuildConfig.yourkeyvalue);
```

Comment: The resource in question is the app name, so it has to be a resource.

Comment: This was not asked by OP

Answer (score 1):

To have an alternative version of a resource in debug builds you can use the debug source set.

`strings.xml` can be found under following path `src/main/res/values`, which means it's in the main source set. If you create a new directory `src/debug/res/values` you can put a new `strings.xml` file in there with values that should be overridden in debug builds. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application Debug</string>
</resources>
```

This will replace whatever value `app_name` has in your main file. You don't have to duplicate all the strings in here - ones you don't include here are simply taken from the main file.

Comment: The resource is not in `strings.xml`.  I'm creating it with `resValue` because I anticipate the number of build variants * product flavors to grow, and I'd like to avoid the need to create a `strings.xml` for every combination.

Comment: If you're creating the original value using `resValue` then you don't have to read it back from resources. You already have the value in your `build.gradle` script. Just assign it to a local variable and use it to create a resource for each variant.

Comment: I tried putting the variable in the `android` scope.  All product flavors run before any build type, so every build type sees the value assigned in the last product flavor.