# String resource from debug variant does not work

Tags: android, android-build, android-build-flavors

I used to have defined an application name as a resource in the gradle:

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lelisoft.com.lelimath"
    resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'LeliMath'
 }
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'LeliMath DEV'
    }
 }
```

Then I found a need for a localization, so I deleted all `resValue` from the gradle and defined in in `strings.xml`:

```
app\src\debug\res\values\strings.xml
<string name="app_name">LeliMath DEV</string>

app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
<string name="app_name">Leli Math</string>

app\src\main\res\values-cs\strings.xml
<string name="app_name">Leli Matematika</string>
```

When I compile my application in Studio, it displays Leli Matematika. I expected LeliMath DEV. I was inspired by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579475/1639556.

Comment: you made a values directory for a custom location. So you have to make the same directory in debug also to make it work. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get it by placing the string here.

```
app\src\debug\res\values-cs\strings.xml
<string name="app_name">LeliMath DEV</string>
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Yes it work but why? Why is there no fallback to values directory within debug build variant?

Comment: If you have multiple variants like debug, release or flavors, build tool first check for the specific variant items. If the resource not available for specific variant then it will take that from main. In your case, you are using region specific values directory(values-cs) so the build tool first checks the debug directory for the file. if it is not available then it will take that from the main directory.

Comment: I would expect that if cs in debug is not defined, it will look up default string in debug. And if not found then it would use main.

Comment: Unfortunately the build system not designed like that. It will always look for main resource. There is no way to tell the build system to do that.