# How to set app_name based on built type and build flavor using gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have my `bluid.gradle` set different app_names for debug and release like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App Dev"
    }

    release {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App"
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add two flavors for two different targets of the app:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App Dev"
    }

    release {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    app {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App"
    }
    client {
        ...
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Client App"
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I set the app_name to match this output:

- appDebug -> "App Dev"
- appRelease -> "App"
- clientDebug -> "Client App Dev"
- clientRelease-> "Client App"

I have seen some answers using resources, but I want to know if there is a way to do so just using gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change app name per Gradle build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type)

Comment: Thanks @ReazMurshed. I'm trying to find a way to do this using gradle (if possible)

Comment: Please delete your question as this is a duplicate. We don't encourage duplicate questions in SO.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do so using gradle, not resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
flavorDimensions "stage", "production"
fav1Debug {      
    dimension "stage"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "App Debug"
}
fav1Production {      
    dimension "production"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "App Production"
}

fav2Debug {  
     dimension "stage"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "Client Debug"
}

fav2Production {      
    dimension "production"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "Client Production"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**just like this**

**build.gradle**:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            manifestPlaceholders = [app_name          : "@string/app_name_debug_version"
                                    , app_icon        : "@mipmap/ic_launcher_debug"
            ]
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            manifestPlaceholders = [app_name          : "@string/app_name"
                                    , app_icon        : "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            ]
        }
}

productFlavors {
    client {}
    app {}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<application
        android:name=".common.base.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="${app_icon}"
        android:label="${app_name}"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label,android:icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of app_name in AndroidManifest.xml file for Launcher activity like

```
<activity
         android:name="com.aone.adesa.Main.SplashScreenActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity
```

Comment: Thanks Pritesh. The issue is not how to use the app_name, is how to generate the right app name given the flavor and build type

Comment: Make use of dimensions

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
flavorDimensions "roadmap"

productFlavors{

    production {
        dimension "roadmap"
        applicationId "com.yourappid"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }

    preview {
        dimension "roadmap"
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }

    demo {
        dimension "roadmap"
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
        versionNameSuffix "-alpha"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470850/how-to-get-a-resource-value-in-build-gradle)

Using `manifestPlaceholders`