# Parsing resources with aapt2

Tags: android, gradle, aapt2

I need to parse string resources at the project build stage.
Before the aapt2, I did it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275461/how-to-replace-strings-resources-with-android-gradle). Now with the advent of aapt2, resources are collected in the *.arsc.flat format. Disabling apt2 is not suitable as a permanent solution. How can I parse resources in this format?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to parse the output APK and get the symbols from it.

However, it is a lot of work and if you just want a hacky quick-fix you can instead inspect the `R.txt` file that's output by the `process<Variant>Resources` task. It's basically a list of all the resources in the project, including all the strings. The format is a line per resource in the form of:

```
<java type> <resource type> <resource name> <resource ID>
```

So you need to find all the lines with:

```
int string some_string_name <ID>
```